# How to prevent signtool from asking for a smartcard when signing an .EXE file?

Tags: code-signing

On my development computer using Windows 10, I sign my .EXE files using  a GlobalSign hardware token where an EV signing certificate is stored, using the command (as recommended on the GlobalSign.com site) in a batch file:

signtool sign /a /tr http://timestamp.globalsign.com/tsa/r6advanced1 /td SHA256 /fd SHA256 %1

Then, I get two times a prompt window like the following, where I have to click "Cancel" (i.e. "Abbrechen" in my German environment) each time:

[Smartcard request prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cO8AY.png)

After that, the signing proceeds successful without further problems.
How do I get rid of these superfluous and senseless prompts?
(Especially, as I do not have a smartcard reader connected to my computer, and I do not remember to have used anything from Broadcom Corp.)

I searched GlobalSign.com and Google in vain for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that I have found the solution myself. My signtool.exe (copied from an earlier installation of Windows SDK to my utility directory) was from 2010. After I replaced it with the signtool.exe from a current SDK installation (now dated 2023-05-12), the problem has disappeared.